# Chromecast app not connecting to the device

Tags: android, chromecast

i have developed Chromecast receiver app and it worked without error previously.

But now i have updated SDK and  compiled app with API level 23.

[image]

App is using CastCompanionLibrary. Here is the Git project that referring to this project.

[CastVideos-android](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android)
I have linked latest CastCompanionLibrary to the project

[CastCompanionLibrary](https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android)

But its showing " Could not connect to the device" every time. Its showing available device's correctly. Anybody know reason for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Found the error.the device that im testing got old play service apk. when i update the play services to latest one it started to cast video without error. But app didn't prompt update message for play services.